# How to install sklearn package in Jupyter Notebook in pycharm

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pycharm

I  was receiving the following error. I have installed the package in the pycharm. Now the module is available in main.py file but the module is not available in jupyter notebook that I am using in pycharm.
When I run the cell I still get the following error in jupyter notebook  but not in main.py file.
Please help me out!

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-1-7a030bc34e9f> in <module>
----> 1 from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
      2 import numpy as np
      3 
      4 from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
      5 import numpy as np

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'
```

Comment: probably you have two Pythons installed and you installed module in one Python but you use different Python to run Jupyter. Check `import sys` `print( sys.executable )` to get full path to Python used in Jupyter - and then use this path to install modules `/full/path/to/python -m pip install sklearn`

Comment: @furas   How can I change the python for running jupyter ?

Comment: normally you have install Juputer in this python `python -m pip install jupyter` and use this python to run it `python -m jupyter`